# NodeJS url param or body param for update and delete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an API in NodeJS and am not sure whether to update and delete items based on an ID passed in the URL or request body.

URL parameter:

```
// Update a todo
app.put('/todos', (req, res) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const newTodoContent = req.body.todo;

  // rest of the code
});
```

Request body:

```
// Update a todo
app.put('/todos', (req, res) => {
  const id = parseInt(req.body.id);
  const newTodoContent = req.body.todo;

  // rest of the code
});
```

I can make both work. Which would be the recommended way? Is there any difference in code efficiency or security? Based on my research the URL parameter is more common but it seems more elegant passing the id in the request body.

Comment: It's really up to you but proponents of REST would say that identifiers for `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` should be in the URL, preferably as path parameters... `app.put("/todos/:id"`. The last (`DELETE`) should not have any request body

Answer (score 1):

Preferred way is to pass the id of the element in the url as params as follows

> app.put('/todos/:todoId', (req, res) => {
> // rest of the code
> });